# if with duplicated code or if with duplicated conditions

Tags: java, performance, optimization

Given the next code samples, What do you think is better, or can you think of another way to code this in a more elegant way?

Duplicated condition in if (two times checking for 'b')

```
if(a || b) {
  doAB();
}
if(b) {
  doB();
}
```

Duplicated code (two times doAB()):

```
if(a) {
  doAB();
}
if(b) {
  doAB();
  doB();
}
```

Or a mixed...

```
if(a || b) {
  doAB();
  if(b) {
    doB();
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

A coworker proposed this:

```
int mask = a?1:b?2:0;
switch(mask) {
  case 2:
    doB();
  case 1:
    doAB();
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: The second snippet could be functionally wrong, since it would call `doAB()` twice if both `a` and `b` are true.

Comment: I want to avoid duplicate code

Comment: if b would be true, in the ffirst and last, you would run doAB twice.

Comment: If it is a, it cannot be b and vice versa

Comment: @danielsp it depends on your requirements, which we don't know

Comment: In that case `a || b` is always `true`.

Comment: Better according to what criteria?

Comment: I think I'll choose the coworker solution. 0 duplications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A completely different perspective: avoid using if/else stuff.

In OO languages, you can use polymorphism instead of if/else. Instead of asking for some state; to then call a specific method; you simply call a method on some object; and the type of object will make sure that the method does the correct thing.

In other words: at some point, you decide which concrete class has to be instantiated; and later on, you don't worry any more.

You know, the smalltalk language does not even have *if* (as keyword/language build int).

Of course, you should not go in and just replace your one if with another one. Instead, you could step back and figure if and then how your problem could be re-framed; to make use of polymorphism.

You can turn here for a pretty good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc&list=PLD0011D00849E1B79&index=4) how that can look in reality.

Comment: But in the example he has a boolean type primitive... Could you explain how are you planning on overloading with it? Did you mean create a factory that takes a boolean and instantiates 2 different classes based on its value? If so, that seems extreme measure to resort to just to avoid if/else. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Palcente The question is: where is that "a" coming from? And yes, that is exactly how good OO design works: your business logic, those objects that really do "real work", they rarely use "new". Instead, some *framework* creates objects; based on configuration information, or other meta information. And then, after all the objects have been created, you just make method calls. If you are curious, I recommend you to turn to the video (link added to my answer) and spent 30 minutes on that. Worth each second!

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing the first one is best given the second one is most likely incorrect. I would use the form you consider simple and less error prone.

The second example most like should be

```
if (a) {
  doAB();
} else if (b) {
  doAB();
  doB();
}
```

> If it is a, it cannot be b and vice versa

In which case you don't need two conditions. It should be a == !b

```
// a || b is always true
doAB();
if(b) {
  doB();
}
```

Comment: it can be the case where a and b are both false

Comment: @danielsp In that case, I would stick with the first option as it seems less error prone.